# How to define a variable with a subscripted part

Tags: subscript

I have looked around, but found no real answer for this.
I generally use Mathematica for thermodynamics and electromechanical equations and for this, to keep a good overview, i got used to defining variables with a subscripted explanation like so:

```
Subscript[Z,motor] := Quantity[60, "Ohms"]
```

Mathematica will mess this notation form up when used in calculations.

I would still prefer to do my definitions this way, but have come to realize that it may well be to impractical in Mathematica?

Comment: Yes. It is mostly discouraged to use `Subscript`ed and `Superscript`ed variables. A striking reason is that your definition is not stored in the variable `Z` (try `??Z` to see that), but within `Subscript`! (Try `??Subscript`.) For example, resetting `Z` does not reset the subscripted `Z`s.  This is diametral to what you would expect from `Subscript` (but it is perfect Mathematica logic).

Comment: Then what would be a recommended format for defining variables, in a way that clarifies the variables purpose?

Comment: What about `Zmotor` or `ZMotor`? Well, many people would tell you to avoid variable names starting with a capital letter (knowing that single letters such as `C`, `D`, `E`, `I`, `K` and a few others would not work, this still would rarely collide with built-in symbols), so `zmotor` or `zMotor` might be better. Never ever use `Z_motor` and similar things as an underscore has a built-in meaning (it defines patterns).

Comment: And how would that work if I have multiple variables with number indexing? Like if i have the P1 effect of a motor and i install another motor. Then i would normally call them by Subscribt[P1,1] and Subscribt[P1,2]. If i write those in the format you tell, then it would be p(which is the variable name for pressure)11 and p12. Which would give me no chance of keeping a sensible overview.

Comment: Put them into arrays.

Comment: Could you give an example of that please. I tried looking up on Arrays and using them for defining a set of varibles. But doing it the way i asked before, give me a "SetDelayed: Tag Array in Array[P1,1] is Protected"?